# What version supports REST API/OAuth

Tags: api, magento-1.5, oauth

What is the minimum version of Magento that exposes/supports a REST API and OAuth support?

Is there any support for REST API and OAuth in Magento 1.5.1?

Comment: It is possible to port REST API to 1.5.1 because in magento it is implemented as a wrapper on SOAP API (more or less). But I don't think time needed worth it, you should better update to 1.7.

Comment: @Zyava I agree. In this case, I am consuming the API and will not be modifying the Magento code itself. Thank you for the info though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum version for Rest API is Magento v1.7.0.0.

There should not be any Rest API in a clean version of Magento 1.5.1.0. I would expect it would be easier to plan an upgrade to 1.7 then it is to get Rest working on a 1.5 install.

**Source**

[Magento 1.7.0.0 Release Notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.7.0.0%20%28Apr%2024,%202012%29)

[The Magento REST API: A Better Way to Integrate Business Applications](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/the-magento-rest-api-a-better-way-to-integrate-business-applications/)

Comment: can u pls help me -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334 @kab8609