# Rest API - magento 1.9 - Return 403 Access denied - Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception::HTTP_FORBIDDEN - format - https://abc.in/api/rest/customers

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

**Error :** Rest API for customer return 403 access denied error.

**Format :** website/rest/api/customer -> 403 access denied error

Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception::HTTP_FORBIDDEN

[image]

Comment: Are you using POSTMAN ? and which method you're using ?

Comment: Share your url, url method and please check your token is valid or not.

Comment: @AdityaShah I just simply enter in url like websitename/api/rest/products    not working, in localhost localhost/magento/api/rest/products returns my products in json format.

Comment: @AdityaShah How can i check my token?

Comment: Yeah zus i understand your concern but when url is redirected at 404 it means your url method or url might be wrong, so i need more details :)

Comment: Haven't you passed the Authentication token ?

Comment: I am just new to API, can u pls guide me? How can i configure, in localhost i get products like : https://snag.gy/UtviXu.jpg but live site not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84514/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-zus).

Comment: @AdityaShah Can you join with chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84529/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-zus).

Comment: @AdityaShah Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84568/discussion-between-zus-and-aditya-shah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error : Rest API for products return 404 page error in Live Site.

**Retrieve the list of products for Admin user with OAuth authentication**

```
<?php
/**
 * Example of retrieving the products list using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 * Preconditions:
 * 1. Install php oauth extension
 * 2. If you were authorized as a Customer before this step, clear browser cookies for 'yourhost'
 * 3. Create at least one product in Magento
 * 4. Configure resource permissions for Admin REST user for retrieving all product data for Admin
 * 5. Create a Consumer
 */
// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://yourhost/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://yourhost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://yourhost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Comment: what is the error mean : https://snag.gy/0i9SUF.jpg?

Comment: finally get the oauth_token,oauth_token_secret,oauth_callback_confirmed, then what i need  to do?

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify a few things.

1. Accessing `https://www.example.com/api/rest/products` from your
   browser shouldn't return a list of products like your
   [screenshot](https://snag.gy/UtviXu.jpg) shows. It should return a 403 with access denied,
   unless you passed in credentials - it doesn't sound like you did?
2. According to your question, on your live website, you tried `https://www.example.com/api/rest/customer` and you're getting a 404, that's because that endpoint doesn't exist. You need to add an **s**
   to customer**s** like so `https://www.example.com/api/rest/customers`
3. What you're seeing in your browser is not `json` it's `xml`

Comment: Updated https://snag.gy/LcnQVP.jpg  like customer to customers getting error, can you guide me solve the issue?  FYI - http://localhost/anusthana/api/rest/products return products values.

Comment: There is no issue, unless you are authorized you should not be able to access that URL from a browser. You need to be passing along API credentials

Comment: Also you realize that on your local you are looking for products and on your live you are looking for customers

Comment: Yes, you are right. https://www.example.com/api/rest/products not return products, how can i pass my credentials?  @haim